# Google Apps Script runs twice when deleting or appending rows. Any possible workarounds/solutions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

For some reason, my script is being run twice onEdit (deleting two rows) and onFormSubmit (appending two rows). Has anyone else encountered this issue? I'm trying to find a possible workaround by checking if the row already exists in the sheet to fix the appending, but have no idea how to stop the deleting issue. I can't find information on this issue anywhere.I have attached my whole script, and would appreciate someone looking at it to see if it is an issue with my scripting, but have marked the appendRow and deleteRow sections with //****** to make these parts easier to find

```
function onFormSubmit() {//Distributes form submissions to the appropriate sheets depending on format and audience whenever new submission is made
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var responseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Item Request");
  var lastSub = responseSheet.getLastRow();//retreives last row (assumed last submission);

  var tsCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 1);
  var lnCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 2);
  var fnCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 3);
  var lCardCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 4);
  var phoneCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 5);
  var audienceCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 6);
  var formatCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 7);
  var genreCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 8);
  var titleCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 9);
  var authorCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 10);
  var isbnCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 11);
  var pubCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 12);
  var staffCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 13);
  var notesCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub, 14);

  var tsVal = tsCell.getValue();
  var lnVal = lnCell.getValue();
  var fnVal = fnCell.getValue();
  var lCardVal = lCardCell.getValue();
  var phoneVal = phoneCell.getValue();
  var audienceVal = audienceCell.getValue();
  var formatVal = formatCell.getValue();
  var genreVal = genreCell.getValue();
  var titleVal = titleCell.getValue();
  var authorVal = authorCell.getValue();
  var isbnVal = isbnCell.getValue();
  var pubVal = pubCell.getValue();
  var staffVal = staffCell.getValue();
  var notesVal = notesCell.getValue();
  //***any other additions will need to be reflected at the end of the if statement below

  //the following if statement determines which sheet the response values will be copied to

  if(audienceVal == "Spanish" || formatVal == "e-Book" || formatVal == "e-Audio") {
   var selector = "Silvia";
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  }
  else if(audienceVal == "Juvenile") {
    var selector = "Hannah Juv.";
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  }
 else if (audienceVal == "Young Adult") {
    var selector = "Hannah YA";
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  }
  else if (formatVal = "DVD" || formatVal == "Blu-Ray") {
    var selector = "Jacki DVDs";
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  }
  else {
    var selector = "Jacki";
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  } //end if statement

  targetSheet.appendRow([tsVal,lnVal,fnVal,lCardVal,phoneVal,audienceVal,formatVal,genreVal,titleVal,authorVal,isbnVal,pubVal,staffVal,notesVal]); //***any aditions to the values above will need to be added here as well
  var selectorCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub,15);
  selectorCell.setValue(selector);

}//end onFormSubmit

function onEdit() {//copies edited items from individual selector sheets back onto main response spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var actSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var responseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Item Request");
  var actCell = actSheet.getActiveCell();
  var actRow = actCell.getRow();
  var actVal = actCell.getValue();
  var respLast = responseSheet.getLastRow();
  var dataA = responseSheet.getRange(1,1, respLast, 1).getValues();     //compiles an array of data found in column A through last row in responseSheet
  var tstamp1 = actSheet.getRange(actCell.getRow(), 1);
  var tsVal1 = tstamp1.getValue();
  var colEdit = actCell.getColumn();

  if (actVal == "p@ssword" && colEdit == 17) {
    for(i = 1; 1 < dataA.length; i++) {
      if (dataA[i][0].toString() == tsVal1.toString()) {
        responseSheet.deleteRow(i+1);
        actSheet.deleteRow(actRow);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  else if (colEdit == 15) {
    for(i = 1; i < dataA.length; i++) {
      if (dataA[i][0].toString() == tsVal1.toString()) {
        var toEdit = responseSheet.getRange(i + 1, 16);
        toEdit.setValue(actVal);
      }
    }
  }
  else if (colEdit == 16) {
    for (i = 1; i < dataA.length; i++) {
      if (dataA[i][0].toString() == tsVal1.toString()) {
        var toEdit = responseSheet.getRange(i + 1, 17);
      }
    }
  }
  else {return;}
}//end onEdit
```

Comment: Check to see if you have two onEdit() triggers for the same function.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably run a lot faster.  I would check to make sure that you don't have two onEdit() triggers running at the same time.  That could be the source of your double deletings.

```
function onFormSubmit() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var responseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Item Request");
  var lastSub = responseSheet.getLastRow();
  var vA=responseSheet.getRange(lastSub,responseSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var audienceVal=vA[5];
  var formatVal=vA[6];
  if (audienceVal == "Spanish" || formatVal == "e-Book" || formatVal == "e-Audio") 
  {
    var selector = "Silvia";   
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  }
  else if (audienceVal == "Juvenile" ) 
  {
    var selector = "Hannah Juv.";       
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  }
  else if (audienceVal == "Young Adult" ) 
  {
    var selector = "Hannah YA";
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  }
  else if (formatVal == "DVD" || formatVal =="Blu-Ray" ) 
  {
    var selector = "Jacki DVDs";
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  }
  else 
  { 
    var selector = "Jacki";
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(selector);
  }
  targetSheet.appendRow(vA);
  var selectorCell = responseSheet.getRange(lastSub,15);
  selectorCell.setValue(selector);
}//end onFormSubmit

function onEdit() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var actSheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var responseSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Item Request");
    var actCell=actSheet.getActiveCell();
    var actRow=actCell.getRow();
    var actVal=actCell.getValue();
    var actLoc=actCell.getA1Notation();
    var last=actSheet.getLastRow();
    var respLast=responseSheet.getLastRow();
    var dataA=responseSheet.getRange(1, 1, respLast, 1).getValues();
    var tstamp1=actSheet.getRange(actCell.getRow(), 1);
    var tsVal1=tstamp1.getValue();
    var colEdit=actCell.getColumn();
    var beenHere=false;

  if((actVal=="p@ssword" && colEdit==17) || colEdit==16 || colEdit==15) 
  {
      for(var i=1;1<dataA.length; i++)
      {
          if(dataA[i][0].toString()==tsVal1.toString())
          {
            switch(colEdit)
            {
              case 17:
                if(!beenHere)//replaces the old break. Only do this once.
                {
                  responseSheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
                  actSheet.deleteRow(actRow);
                  beenHere=true;
                }                 
                break;
              case 15:
               var toEdit = responseSheet.getRange(i + 1, 16);
               toEdit.setValue(actVal);
               break;
              case 16:
                var toEdit=responseSheet.getRange(i + 1, 17);
                toEdit.setValue(actVal);
                break;
            }

          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried deleting all of my triggers as well as any copies I had of the sheet (I'm not sure if those would cause an issue or not?), then re-enabling the ones for this spreadsheet, but it is still having the same issue. Also, I appreciate your rewrite, but there seems to be some logic issue. It sends all of the responses to the sheet labeled "Jacki."

Comment: I've had similar problems and I just don't use simple triggers except for onOpen and I always keep that one in the top of the Code.gs file.  I'll look into the logic a little close and see if I can resolve why the responses are going to Jacki

Comment: Any chance you have two form submits like one in the spreadsheet script editor and one in the form script editor?

Answer (score 0):

If you use onEdit(e), then you shouldn't create trigger. It automatically trigger by it self when edit changes. If you create a trigger, then this function will be triggered two times.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tkxY.png)